# passing data wtih ajax using python's tornado in jupyterhub

Tags: javascript, jquery, python-3.x, tornado, jupyterhub

I am attempting to do something very simple. There is a modal on my page designed to show up whenever a button is clicked. The buttons are a cell in a  in my page's table. The button should launch the modal, and display data inside of that modal based on the rest of the row data. Specifically, one cell: the ID. I am using the python backend to grab a set of data from my DB based on the ID of the click. I have tried as hard as I can to make progress on this on my own.

I am using jquery to handle the click, and all of this is running inside of a jupyterhub server.

Here is the api method to fetch the id from the page:

```
JHAPI.prototype.api_request = function (path, options) {
    options = options || {};
    options = ajax_defaults(options || {});
    var url = utils.url_path_join(
        this.base_url,
        'api',
        utils.encode_uri_components(path)
    );
    $.ajax(url, options);
};

JHAPI.prototype.get_sg = function (sg_id, options) {
    console.log(sg_id);
    options = options || {};
    this.api_request(
        utils.url_path_join('securitygroup', sg_id),
        options
    );
};
```

Here is the jquery on the page that calls it:

```
 $(".rules").click(function () {
      var el = $(this);
      var id = $(this).closest("tr").find(".sgid").text();
      var dialog = $("#rules-dialog");
      dialog.find(".rules-sg").text(id);
      console.log(api.get_sg(id, {}));
      dialog.modal();
  })
```

and finally the python:

```
  class SecurityGroupAPIHandler(APIHandler):
  async def get(self, sg_id):
      data = ["test"]
      self.write(json.dumps(data))

  default_handlers = [
  (r"/api/user", SelfAPIHandler),
  (r"/api/securitygroup/([^/]+)", SecurityGroupAPIHandler),
  (r"/api/users", UserListAPIHandler), ...]
```

As you can see im not actually doing any of the DB fetching yet, im just trying to get the `console.log(get_sg(...)` to actually sucessfully log *something*. Currently it's returning undefined. However, the `console.log` inside of the `get_sg` function is being called successfully and printing the correct id, so I'm 99% sure this is happening on the python side. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Are you sending the appropriate `Content-Type` header for JSON from your handler?